# Optimizing merge-with in Clojure

Tags: clojure

The following works fine for small lists (< 500), but it hangs indefinetely for larger lists (> 2500). Is there a better way to achieve this effect without failing?

```
(def errors '({:a-key
   ["some string"]}
  {:a-key
   ["some string"]}
  {:a-key
   ["some string"]}
  {:a-key
   ["some other string"]}))

(def unique-errors (apply merge-with (comp distinct into) errors))

;; =>  {:a-key ("some string", "some other string")}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem with your code, I think, is not that it's slow, it's that it leads to a stack overflow, because `distinct` is called once for every new error, and it's lazy, so when printing the result, there are a lot of "nested" `distinct` calls.

But anyway: Use sets for things that should not contain duplicates. Using sets leads to the following, which is a little bit faster and does not lead to stack overflows.

```
(def errors (repeat 5000 {:a-key #{"some string"}}))
(apply merge-with into errors)
```

Comment: With the original data structure, `(apply merge-with into (set errors))`.

Comment: @A.Webb only if there's only one key or that duplicates go in hand (dupliacte maps vs duplicate entries).

Comment: I was assuming the latter, but you are right, this would not be the same as the OP solution.

Comment: Is it really fair to call this a "stack overflow"? Perhaps the original code uses the stack inefficiently, and maybe could lead to an overflow with larger data, but I'm pretty sure that the JVM would let us know if an overflow occurs. :-)

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, it results in a java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Comment: @oskarkv The OP said that the code "hangs indefinetely [sic]". I've never known a `StackOverflowError` to exhibit that behavior. Good to keep tucked in the back of my mind, I guess.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah, that's a bit weird. Dunno what development environment he is using.